# Youtube Watch history has stopped updating since Aug, 7th update. Now I get no new recommendations with WH turned on

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, recommendation-engine

Since Aug 7th my watch history has stopped updating entirely.  I watch videos and yet the watch history does not list them.  It does not track watched progress on videos.  It does track searches made.  But the Recommended section on my youtube homepage never updates it just keeps listing. the same videos.  My watch history is turned on but it does not update at all. This is in effect across all the platforms I watch youtube on, seems to be on youtube's side of my account not a platform issue.

Any ideas as to how this can be remedied?  Google search results are less than useful on this subject.

Watched videos: no update on watch history no change to recommended videos.
Cleared older data on the watch history: no change.
Paused and unpaused watch history: no change.
Checked different platforms, IoS, AndroidTV, PC all show the same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my entire history, turned it off and left it off of several hours, when I came back and turned watch history tracking on it immediately started working correctly again.